# How to get the features belongs to a wsp file in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell

how to get the features belongs to a wsp file in sharepoint 2013
i deployed a farm solution  there is any option to get features related to this farm solution  using powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$name = "<name of solution package>"
$sol = Get-SPSolution $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
foreach ($grp in Get-SPFeature | where {$_.SolutionID -eq $sol.id} | Group-Object SolutionId) {
    Write-Host $sol.Name '(ID:' $sol.ID '), Count:' $grp.Count
    foreach ($fd in $grp.Group | sort DisplayName ) {
        Write-Host $fd.DisplayName '-' $fd.Id '(' $fd.Scope ')'
    }
    Write-Host
}
```

Comment: i will run above script after i add the solution package to sharepoint farm?

Comment: Hi there is any option it show which feature is activated?

Comment: Yes, after the WSP is deployed and you can use '(Get-SPFeature -Identity <FEATURE> -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Farm/-WebApplication/ -Site/-Web ) -ne $null' to check if feature is activated

Answer (score 1):

Get feature list from farm solution

```
$packageName = "sharepointprojectfarm.wsp"
$solId = (Get-SPSolution $packageName).Id
Get-SPFeature | where {$_.solutionId -eq $solId}|select DisplayName, Scope
```

## List all farm solutions with features (got from: http://bramdejager.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/get-features-grouped-by-solution-package/)

```
foreach ($grp in Get-SPFeature | Group-Object SolutionId) {
    $sol = Get-SPSolution -Identity $grp.Name -ErrorAction "Continue"
    Write-Host $sol.Name '(ID:' $grp.Name '), Count:' $grp.Count -ForegroundColor Blue
    foreach ($fd in $grp.Group | sort DisplayName ) {
        Write-Host $fd.DisplayName '(' $fd.Scope ')'
    }
    Write-Host
```

}

Read more: http://m.mypowershell.webnode.sk/news/get-features-list-from-wsp-solution/